# Cannot escape backslash

Tags: python, regex

I am using pexpect and I am trying to match the regex. So, I am trying to match the regular expression in a separate program but the backslash near "x" is not escaping. I tried many things. Single '\' supposed to escape special characters that's working, double backslash supposed to escape single backslash, but its not doing that.

```
>>> import re
>>> a=re.compile(r"\[a-z][0-9][a-z]")
>>> print(a.match("\x1b")
```

**Output:**
None

```
>>> import re
>>> a=re.compile("\\\\[a-z][0-9][a-z]")
>>> print(a.match("\x1b"))
```

**Output:**
None

```
 >>> import re
 >>> a=re.compile("\\[a-z][0-9][a-z]")
 >>> print(a.match("\x1b"))
```

**Output:**
None

Can someone explain how to include the backslash in this pattern. I referred all the similar questions and tried everything. Nothing is working

Comment: Use raw string literals when defining regex. `re.compile(r"pattern")`

Comment: You need to write four backslashes or use `r'...'`.

Comment: I tried what you guys suggested to me but it's not working. I changed my question, kindly refer that.

Comment: You need to apply the information from the duplicate to both the pattern to be matched and the string you're passing to `match`. Namely, `"\x1b"` needs to either be `"\\x1b"` or `r"\x1b"`. When you do that, the second regex pattern (`"\\\\[a-z][0-9][a-z]"`) will match. Your first regex pattern with still needs an extra \ like this: `r"\\[a-z][0-9][a-z]"`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Jeff Bridgman